# In Django, how do I serialize a QuerySet that returns a dict object (created with .values())

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-serializer

In Django 1.10 I am trying to serialize an QuerySet that I obtained from the following query:

```
events_in_period = Event.objects \
.filter(timestamp__gte=start_day,
        timestamp__lte=end_day,
        request__isnull=False,
        name=EventType.COMPLETED) \
.annotate(date=TruncDay('timestamp')) \
.values('date') \
.annotate(completed_count=Count('id')) \
.order_by('date')
```

The main thing is the `.values()` statement that makes this statement return a QuerySet that contains a `dict` rather than a Django model instance.

Therefore the following calls to serialize it

```
from django.core import serializers
output = serializers.serialize('json', result)
```

fail with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Any suggestions on serialization without omitting the `.values()` as I need them for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize the dict object into json, then you could import `json`,

```
import json
data = json.dumps(result)
```

The Django serializers are for Django model objects and QuerySets. That's why it's looking for a _meta field.

Comment: Additionally, if your `dict` contains JSON non-serializeable types (like `datetime`), you'll need to convert those. Or, use a library like [jsonplus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonplus) I created exactly to scratch that itch.